# How can I stop an AngularJS $interval?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code inside a function that gets called every 1 or 2 minutes. It simply counts down from 60 to 0 (I've set 60 as the maximum number of iterations).

```
var timer = $interval(
   function (times: number) {
      var retry = 60 - times;
      $scope.retryMessage = "retry + " seconds";
   }, 1000, 60);
```

From what I can see the documentation is suggesting that the $interval must be cancelled but when can I do this?  I assume that I cannot just add:

```
$interval.cancel(timer);
```

after this code.

Comment: you can. sometimes its easier to try things instead of asking a question on stackoverflow :)

Comment: I understand your point but in this case having that code or not having it everything still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$interval returns a promise. you can cancel it like this

```
var times = 60;
var promise = $interval(
   function () {
      var retry = 60 - (times++);
      $scope.retryMessage = retry + " seconds";
      if(retry == 30){ //cancel in 30 seconds instead .. for some reason
          $interval.cancel(promise);
      }
   }, 1000, 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the docs it looks like this should work.

```
$interval.cancel(timer);
```

Comment: Depends when you want it to stop.